# Multiple Active Directory in one Azure DevOps Organization

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have one Azure DevOps Organization tight with Active Directory name ABC(AD name).  I have a user from another active directory(AD name - CDE) need access to the Azure devops organization but I can't find it's username in the user list.  How I can add the CDE active directory into the organization so in future the user from this 2 AD can access to the Azure DevOps organization.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that an Azure DevOps Organization is not supported to connect to 2 AAD directory at a time.

When your organization links AAD, it can only choose one AAD to link.

> How I can add the CDE active directory into the organization so in future the user from this 2 AD can access to the Azure DevOps organization.

You can add the required users from CDE active directory to ABC AAD directory as **Guest Role**.

Then you can find the user name and add the user to Organization.

Or you can directly search the user via user email in **Organization Settings -> Users**.

Even if you can't see the corresponding user name in the drop down list, the invited mailbox can still accept the invitation and join the organization

Then the user will be added to current AAD as a Guest Role by default.

Note: In order for the AAD Guest user to access the organization, you need to make sure the option: **External guest access**  is turned on in **Organization Settings -> Policies**.

For more detailed info, you can refer to the docs: [Add external users to your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-external-user?view=azure-devops) and [Quickstart: Add a guest user and send an invitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal)

**Update:**

To grant the Guest Inviter Role in Azure AD, you can navigate to **Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Roles and administrators  -> Search Guest Inviter Role** and grant the role to your account.

[image]

Comment: When I try to invite the user and send email, I got the error "You are trying to invite user outside your directory but you don't have directory permission to do so."  It's need admin level or owner only able to invite other AAD user?

Comment: You need to grant the **Guest Inviter role** in Azure AD . Then you can invite the user outside the directory successfully.

Comment: @BubbleBub Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: no update yet because we still in the middle of discussion on the solution.  Will update once we try it out.  Thanks

Comment: I'm not able to find where I can grant the Guest Inviter Role in Azure AD

Comment: @BubbleBub Refer to my update, you can find the Guest Inviter Role in Azure AD

Comment: my login account is a User role, it is I'm not able to grant the guest inviter role to me, right

Comment: Yes. You need to contact AAD admin to grant the role to you.

Comment: Lu-MST An extra question hope you can give some advice.  I have a repo is under TFVC in azure devops organization.  I need migrate(or clone) to new organization under different AAD, do you have any advice, any guide or reference?  Thanks